# Get daily average of values of a month

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, average

I want to get the daily average of the values from the sensor 'temp'. 
So for example if I select November it should show me:

```
2019-11-01 = <avg value>
2019-11-02 = <avg value>
2019-11-03 = <avg value>
```

...and so on

So how can I get the average of my values daily? I hope you can understand this.

Sample data:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question, is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```sql
SELECT AVG(value) FROM your_table WHERE MONTH(time) = 7
```

`AVG` will return the average value of your column `value` and you use a condition with `MONTH(time) = the_month_you_want`. For example, `MONTH('1802-07-07')` will return 7, so adapt the query according to the month you want.

Answer (score 1):

The expected result seem to suggest that you want data for November **2019**. You need to group by date part only:

```sql
SELECT CAST(time AS date), AVG(value)
FROM t
WHERE time >= '2019-11-01'
AND   time <  '2019-11-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY CAST(time AS date)
```